# Find a column using VLOOKUP that says TRUE instead of FALSE on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas, index-match

This spreadsheet is for my budgets, I found it on reddit and I've been trying to make it my own. So far it's been going well but I need to categorise every transaction from my bank & obviously there are things I do periodically, like groceries, my phone bill, etc. so I wanted to add the categories for those transactions automatically and the rest I would add manually.

I added a sheet called REGEX, so I use REGEXMATCH to determine if a transactions goes under Groceries, Bills, Entertainment, etc. using regular expression.

So my idea is: in E of Bank #1 and Bank #2 expenses there is a formula that goes to REGEX, finds the range for Bank #1/#2 Expenses, searches for the description, finds whatever value says TRUE in the row of that description and gives it that category. If it **doesn't** find a value that's TRUE, then you leave it blank. A couple of examples:

- Transaction is: Purchase made at the pharmacy w/ Bank #1 --> Column E of Bank #1 expenses would return "Medical".
- Transaction is: Purchase made on amazon w/ Bank #2. I don't have a category for this on the REGEX tab because amazon could be anything --> Column E of Bank #2 expenses would return "" (BLANK).

URL, if you want to play with it, make a copy: [Stack Overflow Budget](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d7nUtP_o2S8wWP8K1cXjCnqp_96-VqdTrlziemPNaFs/edit#gid=930077549)

DISCLAIMERS:

- Most things on the REGEX tab are in Spanish, I live in Spain so my banks are Spanish, so the REGEX is in Spanish.
- This is an **UNFINISHED** sheet.

I've tried a couple of things:
On the Bank #1 expenses sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP($C8,REGEX!K3:AC,COLUMN(Idon'tknowwheretogofromhere),0)
```

I feel like this could be done better with INDEX MATCH & I tried that, but honestly I don't have much experience using INDEX MATCH compared to VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this formula in `Bank #2 Expenses` column `E`

```
=byrow(C8:C,lambda(z,if(z="",,ifna(+filter(REGEX!AD2:AV2,sortn(filter(REGEX!AD:AV,REGEX!AD:AD=z),1)=TRUE)))))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to implement this but if 2 rows have the same description it returns the error `VALUE : FILTER range must be a single row or a single column` I've added your formula to the sheet (Column E on Bank #2 Expenses) and an additional row that is has the same description to the LIDL row so you can check it out

Comment: Please try out the updated formula